# Python: Using Tkinter(ttk) to build a simple form

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

What am I doing wrong here?  I would like to get my input value in a variable. When I finish with the input, I will print the variable to the console.  Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Frame(root)
w.grid(row=0, columnspan=3) 

first_label = tk.Label(w, text="myEntry: ")
myEntry = tk.StringVar()
myEntry_entry = ttk.Entry(w, textvariable= myEntry)
first_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=tk.W)
myEntry_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=10)

button1 = tk.Button(w, text='Print in Console')
button1.grid(row=4, columnspan=1, sticky=tk.W)
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button

myValue = myEntry.get()
print(myValue)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are getting the entry value at the start of the program and never again. You need to use a function to get value then print when you need it to.

Comment: Use an IDE program like the free PyCharm Community Edition to write python programs. You will see the errors at your code like the unfinished line you have....

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You stopped in the middle of writing your code and didn't finish:

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button
```

Not only did you not finish this line, you didn't define `on_button`.  Other issues include: `self` undefined; `button1` gets initialized to two different buttons; and you're expecting inline code to respond to an event.

Your program starts out fine but then takes a turn towards random bits of pasted code that don't hang together.  I would have expected something like:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def on_button():
    myValue = myEntry.get()
    print(myValue)

root = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Frame(root)
w.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

first_label = tk.Label(w, text="myEntry: ")
first_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=tk.W)

myEntry = tk.StringVar()
myEntry_entry = ttk.Entry(w, textvariable=myEntry)
myEntry_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=10)

button1 = tk.Button(w, text="Print in Console", command=on_button)
button1.grid(row=4, columnspan=1, sticky=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```